# How do I debug a type instantiation Error?

Tags: anylogic

I have three agents: Buyer, Supplier, and Order. Buyers have a 'supplier' parameter. Order has six parameters of varying types, p1,...,p6. I'm using an Event to govern how often a buyer sends an order to a supplier. My action code in that placesOrder Event is:

```html
Order order = new Order(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6);
send(order,supplier);
```

I get the following error: "Can't instantiate the type Order" in the placesOrder Event. I've used this technique in other simulations but this is the first time I've gotten this error. The java code is basically the same as in other models (different parameters of course). I'm not sure I understand how to begin debugging this one. Any suggestions on where to go from here? Any more info needed?

Comment: can you show the structure of your model? This should actually work so you probably did something weird somewhere... but it's difficult to know

Comment: Here's the [buyer agent](https://ibb.co/P11Rq6L). The parameters being called in the Event are all the correct types in the Order agent (which only has the six parameters so far, no other components like processes or anything like that).

Comment: this is very strange... can you upload the model somewhere to check it out?

Comment: [Here you go.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uKW3_oAlpje6eOQ5hJAJKs7pRb-CdxlW/view?usp=sharing) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you have another generic called Order... so order is a bit of a conflicting name that you shouldn't use if avoidable. Also you have the arguments of your class constructor wrong and they should be like this:

[image: class]

So if you do this, the problem is solved:

```
logservqual_satisfaction.Order order = new logservqual_satisfaction.Order( 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, supplier,this);
```

Comment: Great spot, thx for raising my error earlier, deleted my reply. I honestly didn't know anymore and always avoid instantiating this way... thx for flagging

Comment: Thanks! That helped me fix it. Although, I've used an agent called 'Order' in previous models without any issue...either way, I'm good to go now. Thanks for the help